# Angular 6 groupBy nested component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, group-by, pipe

I have 3 components:

1. Course-List = get all course from backend and list them together
2. Course-Detail = get selected course and give unit and lessons detail
3. Course-Play = when lesson is selected there's a page like pluralsight that present the video and list of videos.

I have this scheme:

```html
[  
   {  
      id:1,
      title:"Course1",
      author:"Dana",
      segments:[  
         {  
            id:1,
            unit_id:1,
            unit_title:"Chapter 1",
            name:"Lesson 1,
            data:"www.video01.com/vid.avi"
         },
         {  
            id:2,
            unit_id:2,
            unit_title:"Chapter 2",
            name:"Lesson 2,
            data:"www.video02.com/vid.avi"
         },
         {  
            id:3,
            unit_id:2,
            unit_title:"Chapter 2",
            name:"Lesson 3,
            data:"www.video03.com/vid.avi"
         }
      ]
   }
 ]
```

In the Course-Detail component, I want to group by unit_id the segments so I'll get this scheme:

```html
[  
   {  
      id:1,
      title:"Course1",
      author:"Dana",
      segments:[  
         {  
            key: 1,
            value: [{
                      id:1,
                      unit_id:1,
                      unit_title:"Chapter 1",
                      name:"Lesson 1,
                      data:"www.video01.com/vid.avi"
                    }],
             key: 2,
             value: [
                      {  
                        id:2,
                        unit_id:2,
                        unit_title:"Chapter 2",
                        name:"Lesson 2,
                        data:"www.video02.com/vid.avi"
                      },
                      {  
                        id:3,
                        unit_id:2,
                        unit_title:"Chapter 2",
                        name:"Lesson 3,
                        data:"www.video03.com/vid.avi"
                      }
                   ]
            }
      ]
   }
 ]
```

I read there's pipe that does that, but I'm getting a lot of errors and I don't think it's good idea I'll use pipe for this purpose.
If I don't use groupBy I have duplicated titles like [here](https://image.ibb.co/iQJjzJ/Screen_Shot_2018_07_22_at_14_26_40.png)

I'll add the relevant code here:

**course.ts:**

```js
export interface ICourse {
  course_id: number;
  title: string;
  autor: string;
  segments: ISegment[];
}

export interface ISegment {
  segment_id: number;
  unit_id: number;
  unit_title: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  data: string;
}
```

**course-detail.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ICourse } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'lg-course-detail',
  templateUrl: './course-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-detail.component.sass']
})

export class CourseDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  course: ICourse;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getCourse(id);
    }

   // Get course detail by id
   getCourse(id: number) {
     this.courseService.getCourse(id).subscribe(
       course => this.course = course,
       error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
   }

   // Pass course to CoursePlayComponent
   passData() {
     this.courseService.send(course);
   }

   onBack(): void {
     this.router.navigate(['/courses']);
   }

}
```

**course-detail.component.html:**

```js
<div id="main" class='course_detail' *ngIf="course">
  <div class="row" id="course_detail_image">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <br>
        <img src="./assets/images/lg-white.png" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="course_detail_header">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <br>
        <h1>{{course.title}}</h1>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-lg-center" id="progress">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar bg-white"></div>
        </div>
        <td>Your Progress</td>
        <br><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="course_detail">
      <div class="container">
        <br>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#Curiculum" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Curiculum</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#About" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">About this course</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Curiculum">
            <h4>Course Overview</h4>
            <br>
            <ul *ngFor="let segment of course.segments">
                <li id="course_detail_title">Unit {{segment.unit_id}}: {{segment.unit_title}}</li>
                <a class="course_detail_item" routerLink="/courses/{{course.id}}/segments/{{segment.id}}" (click)="passData()" ><li>{{segment.name}}</li></a>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="About">
            <h4>Course Topics:</h4>
            <td> text  </td>
            <br><br>
            <h4>Course Expectations:</h4>
            <td></td>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure what dou you want. I suppose you want some like code bellow (I put comments to be more clear)

**Version corrected group by unit_id***

```
  this.coursesBySegmen=this.courses.map(c=>{
    return {
       ...c, //all the properties of courses
             //but segments is returned group by
             //first get uniq values
       segments:c.segments.filter((s,index)=>c.segments.findIndex(f=>f.unit_id==s.unit_id)==index)
       //with the uniq values make a map
       .map(seg=>{  //with each uniq value, return
          return {
            key:seg.unit_id,  //the key
            unit_title:seg.unit_title //<---¡¡ADD a title
            value:c.segments.filter(s=>s.unit_id==seg.unit_id)  //and array with all the keys
          }
        })
    }
  });
```

Sorry, I group by id, not by unit_id. (yet corrected)

I must add a unit_title property to the segmens. When we make a group is util use a new variable (I called "coursesBySegmen")

So you can write

```
 <div *ngFor="let course of coursesBySegmen">
   <p>{{course.id}} {{course.author}}</p>
   <p>{{course.title}}</p>
   <hr/>
   <div *ngFor="let segmen of course.segments">
     <h2>{{segmen.title}}</h2>
     <p *ngFor="let item of segmen.value">
     {{item.name}}
    </p>
   </div>
 </div> 
 <!--only for check-->
 <pre>{{coursesBySegmen |json}}</pre>
```

Comment: in the picture I added, I want that instead duplicate the title of the unit, it'll print only one time the unit and then all the segments that has that unit, like that:

Unit 1: 
lesson 1

Unit 2:
lesson 2
lesson 3

Comment: @OfirSasson, I updated the code. The main error is that I was grouped by "id", not by "unit_id". It's necesarry add to the segmens, not only "key" else add a "unit_title" property too